# Let $G/H$ be a Galois extension and let $N_1$ and $N_2$ be subfields between $G$ and $H$

Tags: abstract-algebra, field-theory, galois-theory

Show that: $Gal(G/(N_1N_2)) = Gal(G/N_1) \cap Gal(G/N_2)$

Um, one direction seems pretty obvious by definition: I believe it's that 
$Gal(G/N_1) \cap Gal(G/N_2) \subseteq Gal(G/N_1N_2)$

Now I have no idea how to that:
 $Gal(G/N_1N_2)\subseteq Gal(G/N_1) \cap Gal(G/N_2)$. Any ideas how to show this? I'm guessing it has to start with using the fundamental theorem of galois theory but I don't know where to start.

Answer (score 0):

$$\sigma\in\text{Gal}\left(G/N_1N_2\right)\implies \sigma x=x\;,\;\;\forall\,x\in N_1N_2$$

But $\;N_i\subset N_1N_2\;,\;\;i=1,2\;$ , so $\;\sigma n_i=n_i\;,\;\;\forall n_1\in N_i\;,\;\;i=1,2\;$

Comment: Hmm, I do apologize but can you explain a bit? I'm a bit new to Galois theory so not everything is obvious to me!

Comment: We know $\;\text{Gal}\left(G/N_1N_2\right)\;$ is the group of all automorphisms of $\;G/N\;$ fixing elementwise the elements of the compositum $\;N_1N_2\;$. But both subfields $\;N_1\,,\,\,N_2\;$ are contained in their compositum, so *in particular* their elements are fixed by any elements of the above group.

Comment: Ah I see that makes a lot more sense. I was wondering, how would you prove that $Gal(G/N_1) \cap Gal(G/N_2) \subseteq Gal(G/N_1N_2)$? I thought it follows from definition but apparently not! Thank you!

Comment: Just the same: if it fixes $\;N_1\;$ **and also** $\;N_2\;$ then it fixes anything generated by them...